# Logistic regression Maximum Likelihood in rapidminer

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, data-mining, rapidminer, sigmoid

I wanted to get the maximum likelihood in logistic regression with this result (I'm really not sure if this is how it looks like):
[image]

I am currently using logistic regression to National Achievement Test(a performance exam for students,NAT -GRADE-REMARKS the Y axis) and their scholastic grade(In the example below ARTS-G12(Grade 12)-Q1(Quarter 1), the x Axis).

I wanted to know the maximum likelihood of students to Pass the National Achievement Test or to get VLM or LM. For my example in the image above the category in the National Achievement Test is VLM(Very Low Mastery) which is set to 1 and the LM(Low Master) Set to 0. VLM and LM are the only categories the student gets.

I wanted to know the maximum likelihood in this graph in order to fit a s like line in sigmoid function. I just really dont know how to interpret the scatterplot below. Do I need to zoom it out? I really cant interpret it

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions. Non-coding questions about ML & data science methodology are off-topic here, and should be posted at [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead; please notice the **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about general (non-coding) ML practice & methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the interpretation of the scatterplot:

the obvious (for clarity): green is VLM, blue LM
each dot means there is X number of students with the given grade on the horizontal axis.
the **coloring** most probably defines X. Guess: the darker it gets the more students with the same grade?

From this graph, it seems a student's grade is not related to a VLM or VL category because there are low and high marks in both categories.

Comment: by the way Snus74 what do mean by the low and highmarks?

Comment: well, i mean ~70 is the lowest mark on the graph, and 100 the highest -

Comment: okey. thanks for that.. Im using feature selection and I thought a relationship will takes place. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: @NathalieJoyGalia no problem, for a more complete answer try to ask the question in a ML forum, the people there will more likely be experts on the topic

Comment: Okey thank you very much. is this the datascience SE forum?.. Okey I will .. You are very much helpful to me.

Comment: yes try data science SE as @desertnaut suggests

Comment: yes. thank you for that. Very much appreciated your help..